# # -*- mode: ... -*- string fallback

Tags: major-mode, file-local-variables

So I know that I can put at the first or second line of a file a line such as:

```
# -*- mode: conf -*-
```

to tell Emacs what major mode I want the file to be opened with.

But if that mode isn't installed I wish Emacs to fallback to a different mode.
For example I wish to use the *apache-mode*, but if it doesn't exist I wish to fallback to *conf-mode*.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 10):

[Found it](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html):

```
# -*- mode: conf; mode: apache -*-
```

It seems that the last valid mode wins, so I need to put the my wanted mode last, and the fallback mode(s) before it.

Comment: Interesting. I suspect that will activate all the named modes (those that are available at least), one after the other. This should do no harm, but might be a bit time consuming. It's a handy trick, though.